# Replication in PG 9 between Windows and Linux boxes

Tags: replication, postgresql

I have PostgreSQL 9 running on Windows 2003 SP2. I am trying to replicate it on a Fedora 12 system running PostgreSQL 9 as well.

I am hitting this error message:

```
/usr/pgsql-9.0/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/pgsql/9.0/data/ -p 5432
2011-02-11 17:43:26 ISTFATAL:  incorrect checksum in control file
```

Because of firewall restrictions, I could not follow the [official instructions](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Streaming_Replication) to the letter. Instead, I zipped the contents of the data directory when the server was offline and copied that to the Linux box.
I ran a sha1deep on both directories and there were no mismatches.
I changed the rights so that only the `postgres` user and group had access to the files.

Now, what can I do for replication to work? I tried with a 'pg_dumpall', but the system complains that the database IDs do no match.

Comment: Are you sure your Linux machine is the same architecture as your Windows one?

Answer (score 4):

To use streaming replication, you have to use the same PostgreSQL versions on the same operating systems. Windows and Fedora are different OS's, that is not going to work for streaming replication.

If you want replication between different versions and/of different OS's, you could take a look at [Slony](http://www.slony.info/).

Answer (score 0):

Done this using Postgresql 9.5.21 as master on `Windows 2012 R2` and slave on `Ubuntu 14.04`.

You have to take care about a few things:

- most similar CPU (page size, architecture, registers). So, you can't mix 64/32bit, or using CPU with different endianess or page size;
- same endianess also for the O.S.: both 32 or 64 bit;
- same major version of PG: 9.5.x with same or other 9.5.x version (that's for streaming replication, that I'm using, Logical Replication works with different versions of PG);

So, I find an already installed PG on Windows Server. Edit `postgresql.conf` to enable replica and PITR, and `pg_hba.conf` to allow connection.

Then moved on Ubuntu and, with PG stopped, I fetched from the master with:

`pg_basebackup -D /tmp/db/ -X stream -R -U postgres -h ip-master`

Then modified configuration and replaced data directory with `/tmp/db`.

Start slave, and is up and running, but look at this:

> 2020-03-18 21:05:31.598 CET [44640] LOG:  database system is ready to accept read 
>   only connections
>
> 2020-03-18 21:05:31.631 CET [44645] LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 36/C2000000 on timeline 1
>
> 2020-03-18 21:05:31.905 CET [44646] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
>
> 2020-03-18 21:05:32.416 CET [44649] postgres@postgres FATAL:  database locale is incompatible with operating system
>
> 2020-03-18 21:05:32.416 CET [44649] postgres@postgres DETAIL:  The database was initialized with LC_COLLATE "Italian_Italy.1252",  which is not recognized by setlocale().
>
> 2020-03-18 21:05:32.416 CET [44649] postgres@postgres HINT:  Recreate the database with another locale or install the missing locale.

Here's the funny thing: replication works, but you can't connect to the databases.

Anyway, if you raw copy the data dir on Windows, it works like a charm.

Of course, if you re-create the cluster with UTF-8, there's no problem at all.

n.b.: thanks a lot to `incognito` and `ilmari` on official IRC PG channel for the hints.